# Are iPhone apps required to work on iOS 5 if it works on iOS 6?

Tags: ios-appstore, ios

My app currently doesn't work on iOS 5, but it does for iOS 6.

Will it still be accepted to the app store?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple's App Store requirements are very vague.  [Here is a good resource](http://www.infoworld.com/d/developer-world/how-get-rejected-the-app-store-854?page=0,1) for learning how to get your app *rejected* from the App Store.

In short, it says nothing about backwards compatibility.